# SP Initiated SSO using SAML and Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, saml, spring-saml, opensaml

Currently I am working with SP initiated SSO using spring security and SAML. Now,during sign in SP forward authn request to IDP and redirect to IDP's login page for authentication. I have used following URL code sample: 
https://github.com/wiwengweng/wiwengweng/tree/master/saml2.demo/src/main/java/org/wso2/identity/saml2/demo for SSO.

Now, I want to use local page for  user's credential rather than IDP's login page.SO can I post credential during SP--->IDP request in assertion which can validate at IDP and redirect to my home page with SSO ? It is feasible ?

Comment: Why don't you try first and see if it's feasible?

Comment: @Alic Actually I dont get the request, how to pass User credential to IDP that's why  I am asking it is possible or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439577/spring-security-saml-own-login-page-instead-of-adfs-login-redirect this question has been asked many times